# Paramiko cannot execute commands remotely

Tags: python

```
    import paramiko
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(hostname='ip', port=22, username='', password='')
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("docker exec -it chb /bin/bash -c 'clickhouse-backup create'")
    stdin.close()
    stderr.close()
```

Print client can log in remotely normally, Exec_ Command remote execution seems not to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

`exec_command` is not well documented. When run, the command starts execution on the server and streams for stdin, out and err are returned. Assuming your example is the full code, you exit the script before the command has a chance to complete. The exit closes the ssh channel which cancels the command. Add code to read stdout and wait for the command to complete.

```
import paramiko
import threading

class ErrReader(threading.Thread)
    
    def __init__(self, stream):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.start()
        self.stream = stream

    def run(self):
        for line in self.stream:
            print("ERR", line, end="")

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname='ip', port=22, username='', password='')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("docker exec -it chb /bin/bash -c 'clickhouse-backup create'")
err_reader = ErrReader(stderr)
stdin.close()
stderr.close()
for line in stdout:
    print(line, end="")
print(stdout.channel.recv_exit_status())
err_reader.join()
```

Comment: I used your code, but it still didn't seem to succeed

Comment: You could create a separate thread that reads stderr like the example for stdout. Does the output give any hints?

Comment: Output needs prompt. Can you give me an example? thank you！

Comment: Not sure. You're saying that the command is prompting for data? You may be able to `stdin.write("response\n")`. There may be other parameters on the command that let it run silently.

Comment: Solved. client. exec_ Command (CMD, get_pty = true), that's good. thank you!